Why the session is not started during an exception in Laravel 11?
I am using Laravel 11.
When I have an exception in my application (for example for a 404 page), I noticed that the session is not started. In my case I would like to use this session (for the translation of the 404 page).
I am a beginner in Laravel, but I think that problem is here :
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
->withRouting(
    web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
    commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
    health: '/up',
)
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    // Use appendToGroup() to add the middleware to the 'web' group.
    $middleware->appendToGroup('web', Localization::class);
})
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    
})->create();

I tried to add a start session in this part
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    session()->start();
})

without success.
What is the good practice to solve that ?

I found the solution and it was so obvious.
Just add a route
Route::fallback(function () {
    return view('errors.404');
});

And in this case, the session is started !
